# How to fill TextFormField with variable value from another sceen in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, forms

well I want to fill TextFormField with variable value using flutter location packages, so the idea here is that I want a method to call that var and make it text in TextFormField

```
TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: isRtl ? HardcodedTextArabic.strAddress2Text: HardcodedTextEng.strAddress2Text,
                          hintText: isRtl ? HardcodedTextArabic.strAddress1TextHint: HardcodedTextEng.strAddress1TextHint,
                        ),
                        

                        **// varibles are in getuserlocation sceen
                        controller: HomeController.latitude**)
```

Comment: please show to codes where the data will come from and where you defined your textEditingController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the value like an argument from the other screen like

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeName, arguments...);
```

Or you can use a state manager to save the value and consume it in the other screen.

In the other screen you recover the value and preload the value in the controller using the initState as the follows:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textController.text = widget.value;
  }
```

I recomend you this cookbook to learn to pass parameters: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments